# Java Swing component black on second screen bug

Tags: java, swing

I developed a somewhat simple GUI in Java Swing, and for some reason I am seeing some spooky behaviour.

On one computer when the swing window is open on the laptop's own screen it looks normal, but when moved to the second screen it turns completely black, even when it is partly in one and partly in the other it is shown correctly on the laptop screen and black on the other.

I can not reproduce it on my own computer (even though I have three screens), so I wanted to ask if anyone else has had similar experiences.

One idea to a reason could be that the laptop and second screen has different color depths, and that is messing with it.

Any pointers as to why it happens and a solution would be most welcome.

Comment: This is likely a video card/driver/OS issue, if it's window, you can try modifying some of the [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html) to see if that helps

Comment: See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367058/application-turns-black-when-dragged-from-a-4k-monitor-to-a-fullhd-monitor)

Answer (score 1):

I just witnessed the same behavior when trying to use Freemind on my secondary monitor. A quick Google seems to indicate that it's a Java bug.
More context :

- JRE 1.8.0_121 (latest version)
- Windows 10
- the bug happens whether the second monitor is configured on the left or on the right of the primary monitor (so probably not an issue with negative screen coordinates)
- the really spooky part is that FreeMind displays properly if I drag the window to the secondary monitor *slowly enough* so maybe there's an issue linked to refresh rates.
- the issue may be linked to the zoom factor set up on each monitor (125% on my primary vs 100% on my secondary) as the window visibly resizes when I move it from one monitor to the other

Hope this helps.

NB: this should be a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet ;)

### Edit April 2018 :

For those still stumbling on this: on the same PC, the bug has disappeared after some software updates. I'm now running JRE 1.8.0_144, Windows 10 Pro 1709 (build 16299.371). My best bet is that a Windows update fixed the issue; window resizing and zoom factors now work much better than a year ago for legacy/Java applications (JMeter, Gimp).

Comment: Oh, I think it could definitely be an answer, if it really is a bug, especially if you could point to the specific JRE bug.

Comment: I agree that it does not answer the question, but as pointed out I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment to the original question. Hopefully my post 1) shows that the bug has been reproduced 2) gives some pointers as to what probably causes or doesn't cause it 3) helps OP figure out the source of his bug.

Comment: I get this bug, even though all DPI settings are 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue with apache-jmeter-r1839892 (nightly build of jmeter 5), my environment information is like below:

- JRE 1.8.0_101 32bit
- windows 10, Version 1607 build 14393.1944.
- Inter(R) HD Graphics 530
- NVIDIA Quadro M1000M

After I upgrade to JDK 10.0.2 64bit, then it works.

The root cause for me is most likely mentioned:
http://www.drastic.tv/support-59/supporttipstechnical/66-javaondualmonitors
Below solution mentioned in above link works as well with JRE 1.8.0_101 32bit

- Start->Control Panel->System
- Click the Advanced Tab
- Click the Environment Variables button
- Click the New button
- For Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
- For Variable value: -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

I also found another workaround: open jmeter, set the 2nd monitor as the main display in Windows and then switch back the 1st monitor as the main display.

I also tried to upgrade to JDK 1.8.0_181 64bit, the issue persists.