# Application turns black when dragged from a 4k monitor to a FullHD monitor

Tags: java, swing, screen, drag, multiple-monitors

My notebook has a 4k display. My external monitor is 1920. When I drag my Java Swing app window from the 4k display onto the external monitor it gets completely black except for the window frame. It doesn't matter whether I maximize it on the external monitor or not.

Here is the `HelloWorldSwing` example I got from Oracle.com. It shows the exact same behaviour.

```
import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldSwing {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It looks like a bug in Swing. Anyway, I have to find a solution/work-around. Any ideas?

I'm running jdk/jre 1.8.0 121.

Comment: 1) *"It looks like a bug in Swing."* Have you searched the [Java Bug Database](http://bugs.java.com/)? If you do and don't find anything, please raise one. 2) Is the graphics card using the latest driver?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That solves the problem for me and for future versions of Java. I agree, that's important and I will do my part. However, I can't tell this a customer.

Comment: Cool let us know the bug report number & I'll look more closely at the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson (experiences, not a flamewar) most of real bugs is only here

Comment: @AndrewThompson internal review ID : 9047804. Will let you know, when the bug report is approved.

Comment: OK nice one. Not a great solution, but how about taking a screenshot of part of the application every NN milliseconds, and if it's black, either move it back to the previous screen, or pop an option pane advising the user to do so?

Comment: @AndrewThompson :-). Sounds like fully compliant to cutting edge UX standards. Even Swing deserves better. I'll keep it in mind as a last resort.

Comment: *"I'll keep it in mind as a last resort."* Yep. Fully agree on that prioritisation of approaches.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Bug got approved: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175527. By the way, I could go on and submit further bugs in the Microsoft bug database, because if I drag Internet Explorer 11 from my 4k to my external display I get very strange scaling issues like a huge window title bar and font size 100 in the url input field. But that's none of my business. However, Chrome works flawlessly.

Comment: Probably the same issue with an interesting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973827/java-swing-component-black-on-second-screen-bug

"the issue may be linked to the zoom factor set up on each monitor"

I experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Basically I added a component listener to my main frame and listen on move events. Whenever the frame is moved I check on which display it is located. As soon as the frame has been moved to another display I set it invisible, then set new bounds located on the "new" display, set the extended state to maximized and finally make the frame visible again.

For the last minutes I wildly dragged windows from one display to another all while jumping for joy. If you also want that much fun in your life, here is the code:

```
mainFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent evt)
        {
            GraphicsConfiguration conf = mainFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
            GraphicsDevice curDisplay = conf.getDevice();
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

            GraphicsDevice[] allDisplays = env.getScreenDevices();
            for (int i = 0; i < allDisplays.length; i++)
            {
                if (allDisplays[i].equals(curDisplay))
                {
                    //the window has been dragged to another display
                    if (i != _currentDisplayIndex)
                    {
                        final Rectangle sb = conf.getBounds();

                        mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                        //it is important to set the bounds somewhere on the new display before setting the extended state to maximized
                        mainFrame.setBounds(sb.x, sb.y, 1000, 800);
                        mainFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

                        _currentDisplayIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent evt)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent evt)
        {
        }
    });
```

Yippie!

Side note: I tried to take a screenshot of the black window earlier. However, the screenshot isn't black, but just normally shows all swing components. That makes me believe, that it is not only a swing issue, but also some sort of a windows/display driver issue. Pressing "printscreen" doesn't trigger anything in java (I guess), but only refreshes the display.

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't encounter such a problem yet on any multi-screen environment I've tried so far with Swing - I might help debugging it.

Try running this code example:

```
public class HelloWorldSwing
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( final GraphicsDevice device )
    {
        final GraphicsConfiguration conf = device.getDefaultConfiguration ();

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "HelloWorldSwing", conf );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        final JLabel label = new JLabel ( "Hello World", SwingConstants.CENTER );
        frame.getContentPane ().add ( label );

        final Rectangle sb = conf.getBounds ();
        frame.setBounds ( sb.x + sb.width / 2 - 100, sb.y + sb.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200 );

        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                final GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ();
                final GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices ();
                for ( final GraphicsDevice device : devices )
                {
                    if ( device.getType () == GraphicsDevice.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN )
                    {
                        createAndShowGUI ( device );
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

This will basically place one frame on each of the screens devices available in your system. It will also provide default screen graphics configuration into each frame.

Check if you have the same problems dragging frame to your notebook screen or not and whether there are any other problems.

**Edit1:** Also it might be quite important to know which JDK/JRE you are using to run your code example since there were some related internal changes. If you are running some old JDK it might not be the best idea on newer Mac OS X versions.

**Edit2:** I would try doing a few more things to find out more:

1. Setup [Nimbus Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) before displaying frames and try dragging them with that custom L&F installed.
2. Setup system (native) look and feel as [shown in the tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) - this might have some effect on Mac OS X.
3. Try to run [Java FX example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) and drag it between displays and see if you get the same problem there or not - you are already using JDK 8 so it should be easily doable. Java FX is just the new UI framework that was introduced some time ago.

And in general I could say that Swing has quite poor support for high-res displays, so even if everything runs properly and you don't get the black screen you will see other issues like the UI being blurry or low-quality text rendering.

Comment: I added my jre version to the question above. I also run your HelloWolrdSwing. Result:

Comment: There is one swing window on each display. Both displayed properly. The text size is physically the same size, which makes it small, but readable on the 4k screen, but impossible to read on the external display. 
I have to resize both windows first, because otherwise I cannot drag them. 
1) I take the window from the 4k display and move it to the external display: Window turns black.
2) I take the same window and drag it back to the 4k screen: All good again.

Comment: 3) Now I take the other window and drag it from the external screen to the 4k display: All good. The text is now also readable but stays physically the same size
4) I take the same window and move it back to the external display: Window turns black.

So no matter what, as soon as I drag one of those windows from 4k to external display, it becomes black.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've updated the post - try going through some more options I've mentioned under **Edit2** part. So far it seems that frame fails to update its graphics configuration upon dragging it to the secondary screen, but there is nothing you can really do about it if it is the main cause of the problem.

Comment: Neither Nimbus nor Native L&F change anything. The JavaFX example works even when I drag it to the external monitor. However, when I try to resize the JavaFX window on the external display it turns black. But only during the resizing process. As soon as I release the mouse button and resizing therefore is finished, it gets properly rendered again.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the Swing frame buffer image update since JavaFX application doesn't have the same problem. Can you actually check if you can still interact with elements on the frame while its fully black? For example put a big button in the middle of the frame, log some output on button action and try pressing it while it is on the secondary screen (when frame is black).

Comment: If button is still working for you (you get the output) - it means that Swing is running normally but just not able to draw UI onto the frame for whatever reason. Though I cannot really offer any solution for that aside creating a JDK issue request, which you have already done. - I've encountered a few small JDK issues over last few years myself (mostly in Swing) and most of them have been solved by now, so it is certainly an option.